# Android - ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I have created a **listView** with a custom Adapter like that:

MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity  {
    private ArrayList<compte> m_parts = new ArrayList<compte>();
    private Runnable viewParts;
    private AdapterArray m_adapter;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        m_parts.add(new compte(1,2));
        m_parts.add(new compte(5,6));

        m_adapter = new AdapterArray(this, R.layout.list_item, m_parts);
        setListAdapter(m_adapter);

        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

                  String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

compte.class:

```
public class compte {

int numcpt;
int solde;

public compte(int id, int solde)
{
    this.numcpt = id;
    this.solde = solde;
}
```

}

AdapterArray.class:

```
public class AdapterArray extends ArrayAdapter<compte>{

private ArrayList<compte> objects;

public AdapterArray(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<compte> objectsin) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objectsin);
    this.objects = objectsin;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    compte i = objects.get(position);

    if (i != null) {
        TextView ttd = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);

            if (ttd != null){
            ttd.setText(Integer.toString(i.numcpt));
        }

    }
    return v;

}
}
```

this is the result:

[image]

but when i click on the item i have to send relative values to another activity
Example: when i click on the first item on the listView the relative values ( 1,2 ) must be sent to another activity same thing with the second item. How can i extract this values and send them with intent ?

Comment: what do you mean by relative values ?

Comment: @Anshul: relatives values of the first item = (1,2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the item at the selected index the following way:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    compte selectedItem = m_adapter.getItem(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityToStart.class);
    intent.putExtra("numcpt", selectedItem.numcpt);
    intent.putExtra("solde", selectedItem.solde);

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Note you need to replace `ActivityToStart.class` with the `Activity` class you want to start.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would to to use fragments, but if you want to make it very simple, you can add code below to the onCLick of the element.

```
    Intent intre = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intre.putExtra("numcpt", numcpt);
    intre.putExtra("solde", solde);
    startActivity(intre);
```